# Fast image conversion to 8 bit palette format in memory

Tags: c#, image-processing, .net-core

I'm writing an application that has critical requirements for fast image processing. There will be a huge amount of images. I need to save them in fast-processible format. So, I decided to save **colorful** mipmaps with 8-bit color depth (using palette) and then save it as a **byte array**. So, I need the way to convert formats very fast and in-memory. Also, it must be **cross-platform** as far as possible (i write code on Windows and will deploy to AWS).

I have tried [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp) and [.NET Core System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/) packages. In the case of ImageSharp, I got almost an acceptable result: the quality of the resized image is perfect, but it works really slowly... I got 12 seconds for 4096x4096 [24-bit full palette image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/16777216colors.png). There are 256 distinct colors in the resulting palette, that is perfect for me.
In the case of System.Drawing.Common library I got much faster conversion speed:

- 900 ms for tiff format
- 2500 ms for gif format.

But, the number of distinct colors in the resulting palette:

- for tiff: 224 (not so good for my solution)
- for gif:  252 (good)
  Also, the resulting image in tiff format has **very** poor quality, so probably it can't be used (maybe I am wrong).

System.Drawing.Common implementation:

```
var parameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 8L);

ImageCodecInfo bmpEncoder = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.FormatID == ImageFormat.Gif.Guid);

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

var allColors = new Bitmap(@"16777216colors.png");

Console.WriteLine("Loaded: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); // 462

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    allColors.Save(ms, bmpEncoder, parameters);

    Console.WriteLine("Saved: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); // 2104

    ms.Position = 0;
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ms);

    Console.WriteLine("Loaded: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); // 2383

    // set to determine palette size
    HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>();

    // Temporary solution. It is needed to replace GetPixel to faster analog
    for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.Height; j++)
        {
            var val = bitmap.GetPixel(i, j).ToArgb();

            set.Add(val);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Palette size: " + set.Count); // 252
    Console.WriteLine("All done: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); // 26345
}

/*
    Output:

    Loaded: 462
    Saved: 2104
    Loaded: 2383
    Palette size: 252
    All done: 26345
*/
```

ImageSharp implementation:

```
PngEncoder encoder = new PngEncoder()
{
    ColorType = PngColorType.Palette,
    BitDepth = PngBitDepth.Bit8,
    CompressionLevel = 1
};

Image<Rgba32> img;

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

using (var file = File.OpenRead(@"16777216colors.png"))
{
    img = Image.Load(file);
}

Console.WriteLine("Loaded: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); // 1302

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    img.Save(ms, encoder);
    Console.WriteLine("Saved: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); // 12608

    ms.Position = 0;
    img = Image.Load(ms);
    Console.WriteLine("Loaded: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); // 12813
}


// set to determine palette size
HashSet<uint> set = new HashSet<uint>();

for (int i = 0; i < img.Width; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < img.Height; j++)
    {
        var val = img[i, j].PackedValue;

        set.Add(val);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Palette size: " + set.Count); // 256
Console.WriteLine("All done: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); // 15807

/*
    Output:

    Loaded: 1302
    Saved: 12608
    Loaded: 12813
    Palette size: 256
    All done: 15807
*/
```

So, the best way seems to be to use System.Drawing.Common implementation, but there is probably will be overhead related to slow pixel reading.
So, **questions**:

- I expected high performance form ImageSharp, so I guess I doing
  something wrong... It would be cool to know how to improve the performance! If anybody knows what I doing wrong please tell me.
- Does it guaranteed that palette colors will be the
  same for any image, so, I will be able to cache any-to-any color difference between these 256 colors?
- Does anybody know the best way to solve my problem in other ways? I'll be glad to see suggestions. The solution must be **cross-platform and fast as it possible up to byte array data representation**

Comment: Sounds like this belongs on code review

Comment: Why not using .bmp file format?  It handles your color domain and may have faster converters (not sure) built into Windows.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1101160/please-help-converting-24-bit-image-to-8-bit - also shares a possible library to try.

Comment: I need a fast way to generate mipmaps from images, that comes from users. Also, I need to implement a byte-by-byte comparison of images, so in any case, the fastest approach will be the image stored as a byte array. It won't use any encoders/decoders when data is needed.

Comment: Honest question : If you need all this speed and cross platform, why are you using C#?  One more for you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b87d0286-39e4-4f38-966c-196eb8130d08/how-to-convert-24-bit-color-image-to-8-bit-color-image-using-c?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: If you want to process bitmaps using the .Net GDI classes, then you should look at using the [Bitmap.LockBits Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=netcore-3.0#System_Drawing_Bitmap_LockBits_System_Drawing_Rectangle_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageLockMode_System_Drawing_Imaging_PixelFormat_) and its example code for retrieving pixel data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Accord` for it. Its hard to say if it is fast. You Need to try it in your scenerio.

You want to have 8bpp image? So you want it to be GreyScale? Then, use this function from `using Accord.Imaging.Filters;`.

```
private Bitmap Create8bppGreyscaleImage(Bitmap bitmap) 
                                  => Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.BT709.Apply(bitmap);
```

This convertion on [This](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/vis/a000000/a003600/a003657/sc09cloud_still_persp_c1440.0500.jpg) jpg image take `500ms`. Produced image look like this: [image]

As you can see, `Grayscale.CommonAlghoritms.BT709` takes `Bitmap` as argument. If you want to byte array, just use `Marshall.Copy`:

```
BitmapData bitmapData = this.Bitmap.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Bitmap.Width, this.Bitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            this.Bitmap.PixelFormat);

        int pixels = bitmapData.Stride * this.Bitmap.Height;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[pixels];

        Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, bytes, 0, pixels);

        this.Bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        this.Bytes = bytes;
```

Loading image as 8bpp byte array by this method (image above) take `18ms`.

It will save byte array to memory. Then, you can unlock bits to your bitmap and save it for example as `.png`:

```
BitmapData bitmapData = this.Bitmap.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Bitmap.Width, this.Bitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            this.Bitmap.PixelFormat);

        int stride = bitmapData.Stride * this.Height;

        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, stride);
        this.Bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        this.Bitmap.Save("test.png");
```

Tells me if my answer was helpful to you. You dont have reference to `System.Drawing.dll` out of the box in .NET Core, you need to add it on yourself

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed response! But I'm afraid I need a colorful image with a static palette. Anyway, it is a great approach to Marshal.Copy and it would be helpful for me if I will decide to use System.Drawing.Common or Accord.

Comment: I dont understand, you want to cut 2 channels and still have colorful image? Its not working like that. When you cut 2 channels and let one it always be gryscale image. Marshal.Copy is good tactic to compute byte stream from image so i think i deserve for upvote ;p

Comment: You mentioned, that System.Drawing is slow. yes, get/set pixel by System.Drawing is slow as hell because every time you call Get/SetPixel() methods all bitmap is loaded to memory, the method take one specific pixel, then whole bitmap is unloaded from memory. By Marshal.Copy you loaded image as byte array (1d array) once by lockbits, then you can unload that array by unclocking bits that i mentioned in my answer. For loading and unloading image to memeory you need to use Marshal.Copy. There is no faster method, even OpenCV and Python can be a little bit slower

Comment: 8 bit colourful pixel represents by a set of colors (ideally, 256). When it needed to get an 8-bpp color from 24 bpp color you need to find the closest color from this set. So, this 8-bit value will be represented as an index of the set.